# Is it possible to toggle the menu bar by pressing the Alt key?

Tags: kubuntu, plasma-5, kwin

How to switch to menu bar (drop-down menus at the top of a window in most applications, see the image) on <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in KDE Plasma just like it's done in Windows and many Linux environments?

Ubuntu 18.04

DE: KDE 5.44.0 / Plasma 5.12.6

WM: KWin

[image]

Comment: For example IceWM does

Comment: "Are you referring to the File, Edit, View menu bar?" exactly!

Comment: "For all applications?" I'm not sure, I can't check it now

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the *File, Edit, View …* menu bar is application-dependent and is not governed by the window manager.

In Kubuntu 18.04+

- With *Firefox*, if you choose to hide the menu bar, you can make it appear temporarily by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
- In *Google Chrome*, there's no such menu bar.
- In Kubuntu's default terminal emulator, *Konsole*, if you choose to hide the menu bar in *Configure Konsole*, you can toggle it on/off using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. *qterminal* is similar.
- In *Gwenview* and *Kate*, you can toggle it on/off using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.
- In *Dolphin*, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> toggles between the menu bar and a "Control" icon that looks like ☰.
- *VLC* has a minimal interface option that is toggled with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. In addition to hiding the menu bar, the bottom strip showing the progress bar and other controls are also hidden.

In other words, it doesn't appear that there's a "global" toggle for the menu bar.

---

Please also look at [How to restore horizontal application menu in KDE Plasma 5?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/516276/61798) in case you've added something that looks like ☰ in your window's titlebar. You'll need to remove that to regain the conventional menu bar.

Comment: Under "switch to menu bar" I mean not just show the menu bar if it's hidden, but switch focus to it to be able to select something from the menu with arrow keys. Now I can open sub-menus by pressing Alt + underlined letter, but not in all programs.

Comment: Is it an application-dependent feature too?

Comment: Are you referring to keyboard accelerator keys like in https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CI60.png ?

Comment: Yeah https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HOk2l-rLSA

Comment: So what is your question now? It seems different than what you expressed in the original question.